# insert data from one table to another - Not Working - possible bug?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert data from one table to another, but I keep getting a weird SQL error. The following is my query along with the error.

```
insert into hs.hs (`field1`,`field2`,`field3`)  select cid,sid,'1' from `tmp1`;
```

now the error

```
1416 - Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field.
```

I don't understand why I'm getting a geometry error there is no geometry involved at all.

By the way my MySQL version is:

```
SELECT VERSION();  Result 5.7.16-log
```

I'm pretty sure I'm doing everything right; Can some one please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Could this be a bug?

Thanks I'm looking forward to some help.

Comment: Try this - 
insert into hs (`field1`,`field2`,`field3`) select cid , sid, '1' from `tmp1`;

Comment: Post the outputs off `SHOW  CREAtE TABLE hs` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE tmp1`

Comment: @kiti I just tryed it same error.

Comment: @RaymondNijland    I just did a show create table all fields I'm querying are int.

Comment: Please mention all the columns contained in both the tables. Its working well for me, as my "hs" table contains 3 fields. If your "hs" table contains more fields then either you have to assign them values by fetching from other table or give them some default values

Comment: @kiti The hs table has 85 fields and the tmp1 has 27 fields for now I'm only trying to populate those fields that I mentioned. Ah!!! now that I think about it I do have a geometry field in hs that I was not populating. I'm going to populate the geo fields and let you know how it works out. I'm now pretty sure this is causing the error.

Comment: @LogicalNonsense sure.

Comment: @kiti Yup that was the problem. Thanks! feel free to post an answer and I will accept it(:

Comment: @LogicalNonsense thankyou :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this -

```
insert into hs (field1,field2,field3) select cid , sid, '1' from tmp1;
```

If this wont work then try please check the columns contained in both the tables. If your "hs" table contains more fields then either you have to assign them values by fetching from other table or give them some default values.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into hs (field1,field2,field3) select cid , sid, '1' from tmp1;
```

Below is the reason why the above query didn't worked

- **INSERT INTO SELECT** requires that data types in source and target tables match
- **INSERT** statement should contain all columns or they should have some default value assigned